# Android x86 bluetooth macbook

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, bluetooth

I have been trying to develop apps and test them on the Android x86 on virtual box. The problem I am having is that it hangs on turning on bluetooth and never actually turns it on. I am using the macbook bluetooth. I have enabled it on virtual box(it has the tick next to it). I was wondering if there was a fix for this as I do not have an Android phone to test this on. Android x86 2.2 is what I am using.

My log cat:

```
I/ActivityManager( 2052): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.project.saff/.FaultScreenConnect }
I/ActivityManager( 2052): Displayed activity com.project.saff/.FaultScreenConnect: 189 ms (total 189 ms)
I/ActivityManager( 2052): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity }
I/ActivityManager( 2052): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.android.settings.bluetooth.ACTION_INTERNAL_REQUEST_BT_ON cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionHelperActivity }
I/ActivityManager( 2052): Displayed activity com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionHelperActivity: 193 ms (total 198 ms)
I/ActivityManager( 2052): Displayed activity com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity: 198 ms (total 198 ms)
D/BluetoothService( 2052): Bluetooth state 10 -> 11
V/BluetoothEventRedirector( 2147): Received android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
I/bluedroid( 2052): Starting hciattach daemon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
D/dalvikvm( 2291): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1414 objects / 101976 bytes in 4ms
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping bluetoothd deamon
I/bluedroid( 2052): Stopping hciattach deamon
E/bluedroid( 2052): bt_enable: Timeout waiting for HCI device to come up
D/BluetoothService( 2052): Bluetooth state 11 -> 10
V/BluetoothEventRedirector( 2147): Received android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: Is there anything interesting going on in your logcat? You can connect to it through the adb: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: Are you talking about the x86 emulator (as for Google TV)? I'm not sure where "virtual box" fits in with respect to the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The x86 emulator for Android on which you can run Google TV, currently only works on **linux with KVM**-supported kernels (and Intel virtualization support in BIOS). *Windows and Mac OS X are not currently supported.*

[System reqs](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You did not state where did you get your Android X86 image from, so I will presume that it is from [www.android-x86.org](http://www.android-x86.org/). This system build requires specific hardware to run, and it might not work trough Virtual Box even if your hardware is actually supported.

For the list of actually tested hardware, see [here](http://www.android-x86.org/hardware-list). On the builds I tested with Virtual Box, mostly work but with limited device support, e.g. camera, gps, bluetooth, wifi are not working (and can't be turned on). There is a guide for Android X86 on Virtual Box [here](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto), and there is [this](http://dev.blogs.nuxeo.com/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html) blog entry that describes how to setup some additional options so you mimic the properties of actual devices (like screen resolution of the phone, etc.)